# Spring Roo No add-ons Known

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo

I attempt the following command in the roo shell

**database reverse engineer --package ~.domain --schema PUBLIC**

and yield the following...

**Spring Roo automatic add-on discovery service currently unavailable**

When I simply attempt to do an addon search I get the following

**No add-ons known. Are you online? Try the 'download status' command**

The download status is fine though. There is potentially an issue with being behind a proxy but I've already fixed the settigs.xml and the proxy settings, unless I am missing anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure there's no content proxy on the network either, as they sometimes prohibit downloading certain file types like .jar for example. Can you execute Eclipse update successfully? Can you add plugins to Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I figured you're using STS, Roo is tricky otherwise. If plugins work then it must be specific to Roo. Will try to verify at home, as here I have the described case of Evil Content Proxy (c).

Answer (score 2):

If this is not related to proxy then probably it is related with a current bug in RooBot Add on registration. See the Jira issues - [ROO-3184](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-3184), [ROO-3191](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-3191). It is not fixed yet.

Comment: The above mentioned Jira issues are now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience.  Whenever I typed **addon list**, roo would doubt I was online.  When I typed **proxy configuration**, roo would tell me I had none configured.

To get roo to use your proxy setup, create a **ROO_OPTS** environment variable and specify **-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true**

Restart roo and it will use your proxy

Answer (score 0):

Tried osgi start command. Download driver and issue ROO command:

```
osgi start --url file:C:\dev\h2DataBase\h2\bin\h2-1.3.168.jar
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the error message, so good luck with a -1.